# JQuery each function create infinite loop

Tags: jquery, each, infinite-loop

The following code creates an animating slideshow. How would we turn it into an infinite loop, IE: so that it goes back to the first slide at the end of the last.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sismain a').css('opacity', 0);

    var slideqnt = $('.sismain a').length;
    var slidecur = 0;
    var slidelay = 0;
        $('.sismain a').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(slidelay).animate({opacity: 1,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
            slidelay += 6000;
            $(this).delay(slidelay).animate({opacity: 0,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin Knight,

you can use the setTimeout function of Javascript to create an infinite loop.

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

If you don't want any pause, just set the timeout time accordingly.

You can also put your each into a while(true){}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = setInterval ( "doSomething()", 5000 );
```

And when you want to stop

```
 clearInterval(interval);
```

setInterval would be the best way, execute the function each 5000 milliseconds

Comment: You shouldn't use the version of `setInterval` that uses `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. Initially call a timeout based upon total time, then later you can keep resetting the current slide number in an infinite loop.

```
$('.sismain a').css('opacity', 0);
    var slideqnt = $('.sismain a').length;
    var slidecur = 0;

    function nextSlide(){
    $('.sismain a').eq(slidecur).animate({opacity: 1,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
    $('.sismain a').delay(2000).eq(slidecur).animate({opacity: 0,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});

    if(++slidecur==slideqnt){
        slidecur=0;
    }
    setTimeout(nextSlide,6000);
}

setTimeout(nextSlide,6000);
```

Hope this helps your case :)